# preprocessor，ifdef

Tags: erlang

When debuging gen_server module, I want to record more details status.

```
init()->
    put(?COMPLETED_COMMANDS,[]),
-ifdef(DEBUG).
    put(?DETAIL_STATUS,[]),
-endif.
    ok.
```

The compiler give the following error.

```
src/benvolio_command_cache.erl:34: syntax error before: ','
src/benvolio_command_cache.erl:36: syntax error before: '.'
src/benvolio_command_cache.erl:33: variable 'DEBUG' is unbound
src/benvolio_command_cache.erl:33: function ifdef/1 undefined
```

How to add debuging code lines in the `*.erl` file's function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro directives cannot be used inside functions.  see [8.5  Flow Control in Macros](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#id80919).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [9. Preprocessor](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html) chapter in the [Erlang Reference Manual User's Guide (Version 11.1)](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/users_guide.html) (September 22, 2020),

- **macros** cannot be *defined* in functions; albeit it is stated indirectly in [9.2  Defining and Using Macros](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#defining-and-using-macros):

  > A macro definition can be placed anywhere among the attributes and function declarations of a module, but the definition must come before any usage of the macro.
- **macro directives** cannot be *used* inside functions (see [9.5  Flow Control in Macros](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#flow-control-in-macros))

---

As for what you are trying to achieve, there is an example in [9.5  Flow Control in Macros](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#flow-control-in-macros) that answers your question:

> **Example:**
>
> ```
> -module(m).
> ...
>
> -ifdef(debug).
> -define(LOG(X), io:format("{~p,~p}: ~p~n", [?MODULE,?LINE,X])).
> -else.
> -define(LOG(X), true).
> -endif.
>
> ...
> ```
>
> When trace output is desired, `debug` is to be defined when the module
> `m` is compiled:
>
> ```
> % erlc -Ddebug m.erl
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> 1> c(m, {d, debug}).
> {ok,m}
> ```
>
> `?LOG(Arg)` is then expanded to a call to `io:format/2` and provide
> the user with some simple trace output.

To belabor the point, when module is compiled without the `debug` macro, `?LOG(Arg)` will be expanded to `true`.

---

See [compile options](https://erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html#type-option) for [`compile:file/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html#file-2), and [`c/\[2,3\]`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/c.html), and command line flags for [`erlc`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlc.html).